# Error occurs when try to implement virtual entity in MS CRM - An OData error occurred

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to implement Virtual Entity in CRM Online V9.1.0.5220. I have created custom ODATA services below are the screenshots -
[image]

[image]

I have created Bank virtual entity in CRM, when I am trying to call the virtual entity I am getting following error 'Entity could not be retrieved from data source. Please try again or contact your system administrator.'

When I am trying to call the virtual entity from browser as  /api/data/v9.1/geo_banks, I am getting below error -

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "0x80050263",
    "message": "An OData error occurred.",
    "innererror": {
        "message": "An OData error occurred.",
        "type": "System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]",
        "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase query, InvocationContext invocationContext, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode, Guid appModuleId, Dictionary`2 optionalParameters)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataExecutionContext.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase query)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataServiceDataProvider.RetrieveEdmEntityCollection(CrmODataExecutionContext context, String entityCollectionName, String castedEntityName, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EntityController.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<GetEntitySetInternal>b__1()\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Action action, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)\r\n   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute(ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Action action)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EntityController.GetEntitySetInternal(String entitySetName, String castedEntityName, CrmODataExecutionContext context, CrmEdmEntityObjectCollection crmEdmEntityObjectCollection, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EntityController.GetEntitySetImplementation(String entitySetName)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)\r\n   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
    }
}
```

}

I have tried to consume https://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/ ODATA service and it is working as expected. 
I know the issue is with the service but couldn't figure out the exact reason as both the services are similar.

Comment: When creating Virtual Entity in CRM, 2 Fields are created ID field and name filed.
Both are required. One is EDM.Guid and other is String.
I see in your Odataservice you have BanksId Edm.Guid and nullable=false. This is perfect but what about name filed and making it nullable=false.
I am not 100% sure but could do try making Bankname(I belive this is name filed you are mapping) as nullable=false and try.

Comment: I have mentioned https://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/ where name field is not nullable=false, but still it is working fine.